# How can three sorted lists be merged with Merge Sort having a O(nlogn) time

Tags: algorithm, merge, big-o

Merge Sort usually goes by 2 lists at a time which means each level has 2^j more sub-problems than the previous.

How can merging 3 sorted lists give the same run time?

Comment: Logarithms to different bases differ from each other by a constant of proportionality (by the change of base formula for logarithms) Any such constant is eaten in the constant in the definition of big oh. Merge-sort by 3 sublists would simply use the base 3 logarithm rather than the base 2 in its complexity.

Comment: Also, it is misleading to say that they have the same run-time. They are in the same complexity class, but algorithms in the same complexity class can differ dramatically in their actual run-time.

Comment: I guess I have to review the basics of Big O then

Comment: The merging itself is only O(n). Btw. logx(n) = log(n) / log(x) = c * log(n)

Comment: To confirm - are you asking whether mergesort, when we split the input array into three subarrays rather than two, runs in time O(n log n)? Merge and mergesort are different algorithms.